# Jolt: Concat of three stings using join in jolt

Tags: json, jolt

we are using the current jolt to concat two strings, when we have more added, how to add in sequence manner

input:

```json
[
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PAFrstNm": "John"
  },
  {
    "PALastNm": "Jammy",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PAMiNm": "T",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPFrstNm": "sam"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPLastNm": "jim"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPMiNm": "E"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPFrstNm1": "jun"
  },
  {
    "PPLastNm1": "san",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPMiNm1": "e",
    "policy": "Name"
  }
]
```

current Jolt:

```json
[
  { // group by LastN/FrstN removed key names 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*LastN*": {
          "@": "@2,policy.&(1,1)fullna&(1,2)"
        },
        "*FrstN*": {
          "@": "@2,policy.&(1,1)fullna&(1,2)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // concatenate the components of the arrays respectively 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*ful*": "=join(' ',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&",
          "$1": "[#2].policy" // deliver back the policy attribute to those objects
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Expected Output:
PAfullnam: First +Mi +Lastname

```json
[
  {
    "PAfullnam": "John T Jammy",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPfullnam": "sam E jim ",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPfullnam1": "jun e san ",
    "policy": "Name"
  }
]
```

**Current output:**

```json
[
  {
    "PAfullnam": "John Jammy T",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPfullnam": "sam jim E",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPfullnam1": "jun san e",
    "policy": "Name"
  }
]
```

*Firstname + last name*

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan can you please help on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this one as the second spec

```json
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "0|2|1": "&2.&1.[#1]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

in order to sort those values by their indexes within the formed arrays. So, use the following spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*LastN*|*FrstN*|*MiN*": "@1,policy.&(0,1)fullna&(0,2)"
          // the order of the part above is not important
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "0|2|1": "&2.&1.[#1]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*ful*": "=join(' ',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&",
          "$1": "[#2].policy" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros Özhan i just tried with  shift as well.
  "*ful*": "=join(' ',@(1,&[0]),@(1,&[2]),@(1,&[1]))"

Comment: Nice to help, please don't forget to upvote @ManimaranDhandapani